# (Sometimes) Multiple geofencing func is not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, gps, geofencing

I am trying to make an iOS app, using Xcode9 and Swift3.

Sometimes, multiple geofencing functions are not working.

```
func startMonitoring() {
self.locationManager.delegate = self

let tokyo = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(35.702141, 139.775123)
self.monitoredRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: tokyo, radius: 100, identifier: "Tokyo")

let newyork = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.759188, -73.984659)
self.monitoredRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: newyork, radius: 100, identifier: "newyork")

let london = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.510058, -0.134471)
self.monitoredRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: london, radius: 100, identifier: "London")

self.locationManager.startMonitoring(for: self.monitoredRegion)
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
print("Enter:" + region.identifier)
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
print("Exit:" + region.identifier)
}
```

Anybody please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: `self.locationManager.startMonitoring(for: self.monitoredRegion)` will only monitor the last location (London)

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you for comment. So, what should I do to monitor multiple locations?

Comment: Just add one by one

Comment: @LeoDabus Problem solved. Thank you for your support!!:)

Comment: You are welcome